# How to untar all files from archive into one single folder, regardless from their folder nesting?

Tags: linux, archive, tar

In one of my applications a user can upload images and archives (ZIP, RAR). When an archive is uploaded, it should be extracted. However, some users will upload archives that contain files in a variety of subfolders (within the archive)

What i am looking for is therefore a tar command that will extract **ALL** the files from within the archive into one single folder, no matter what the structure of the archive is.

Can this be done with a single command? And if yes, what would that command be?

Comment: Have you thought about: Files with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be done with a single command?

No, `tar` does not support the `-j` flag like `unzip` does, or provide any alternative flag.

Checkout the following alternatives:
[TAR – Extract discarding directory structure](https://superuser.com/questions/71846/tar-extract-discarding-directory-structure)